# Missing exif extension on PHP 8.1 fpm Alpine

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I have setup a php server from php:8.1.4-fpm-alpine3.14 using this dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.4-fpm-alpine3.14

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache git libzip-dev zip unzip php8-exif

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip exif \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . .

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN composer install
```

I tried installing a package `spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.0.0` and got this error

> Problem 1
> - spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.0.0, ..., 10.3.4] require ext-exif * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's exif extension.

How do I fix this missing issue? I cannot find `exif` in the php modules list when i execute `php -m`

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you manage to resolve this? I can see you are using `docker-php-ext-install` to add the extension, but you are not enabling it, so doing something like this (not tested in your's)

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip exif \
    && docker-php-ext-enable exif \ // <----- see here
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

If you build your dockerfile and then run again `php -m` in the container you will see it is listed there. However when I tried to run  `composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.0.0` I still get the same error, at least in my case.

UPDATE

Try installing it using `--ignore-plarform-reqs` param, so

```
composer require "spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.0.0" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This worked for me